# Why Does The "NotePad++" Static Software Application Start?

Tags: windows, notepad++, run-dialog

1. There was a time when one needed to add to the `PATH` Environment Variable the Folder to the `NotePad++` Static Software Application in order to start it from the Run Dialog. This folder:

   [image: folder]
2. There was a time when one was typing just `start notepad++` in the Run Dialog in order to start it, although its path was not present in the `PATH` Environment Variable.
3. Now, it is enough just to type `notepad++` in the Run Dialog in order to start it, although its path is not present in the `PATH` Environment Variable:

   [image: PATH variable]

   How does it do it?

Comment: Why are you using the term *Static*? What does that mean in this context?

Comment: @Twisty Impersonator, I think that the _Static_ Term does not influence at all this question. I am currently using something that I am bombastically calling a _Personal Computing Triad_, made of a Laptop Personal Computer, a Tablet Personal Computer and a SmartPhone, which should be comprised only of Mobile Electronic Devices. Therefore, all of the Software Applications that are currently running on them could also be termed as Mobile Software Applications.

Comment: Still, @Twisty Impersonator, due to Historical Reasons, in my head the _NotePad++_ Static Software Application that is currently running on the Laptop Personal Computer is looking to me to be more _Static_ than the _NotePad Plus_ Mobile Software Application that is currently running on the Tablet Personal Computer and on the SmartPhone. Does any of these make any sense at all to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the "Run" dialog and the `start` command in Cmd seem to use the same ShellExecute() function, which has an additional list of locations: the ["App Paths"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration) registry key.

Instead of adding themselves to %PATH%, programs can register the location of individual executables at:

- `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`
- `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`

This has the advantages of not requiring to restart all apps which still have the old %PATH% value, and not cluttering the path with internal executables.

See Microsoft's [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration) for more details.

Comment: Great answer, @grawity. Someone had already added a comment about App Paths before your answer, but somehow it got deleted for some unknown reason. Could you please comment on the following setting as well? Are [App Execution Aliases](https://imgur.com/r6aIp50) related in any way to App Paths?

Comment: Maybe? They're somewhat of a "Modern/Metro app" equivalent to App Paths, but I haven't investigated how they work. (See what you get from `where MicrosoftEdge` in Cmd; if it finds the program it's done through %PATH%; if it can't find it then it works via App Paths.)

Comment: As you can see [here](https://imgur.com/XIowQxA), @grawity, the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _Edge_ Web-Browser is found through the Olden %PATH% Environment Variable as you say. However, my impression is that the original [App Execution Aliases Picture](https://imgur.com/r6aIp50) that I have provided to you earlier is actually talking about Aliases that are some kind of Names and not Paths. I am sure that a lot of people could benefit in time if you could comment on this Feature of the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _Universal Windows Platform_ Software Applications and not only of them.